# How argv[0] works

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I know that `argv[0]` represents the executable file name, but I don't understand how it is implemented — how it gets the filename and options at the **source code level**. At first I thought it was dependent on built-in functions in linux, but then found out that windows also supports it, leading me to believe that it may be done by the compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually part of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), hence the same implementation across compilers and operating systems. From *5.1.2.2.1 Program startup* (page 12):

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the *program name*; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the *program parameters*.

Edit: Following up on Waleed Khan's comment, you can retrieve these values via:

- Linux - [`/proc/self/cmdline`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)
- OSX - [`_NSGetArgc` / `_NSGetArgv`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.25/include/crt_externs.h) or [`[NSProcessInfo arguments]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/arguments)
- Windows - [`GetCommandLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) with [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx)

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify my question ,I want to know how it implementation in `source code` level .

Comment: This is not the answer to the question

Comment: @ZhangYuan It isn't implemented at the source code level. The host system is expected to provide this value.

Answer (score 0):

when the binary is executed, glibc calls the function __libc_start_main, which passes the ball to the system call execve where argv/argc are pushed to the stack.

the kernel parses the stack to populate argv for you.. so if you're interested in modifying or understanding the parsing part, you should look into the kernel execve code, if you follow it in lxr you'll get to this line, which I believe is what you are looking for:
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0/fs/exec.c#L1541

Answer (score -1):

http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/exec.c#l1376
Search for  sys_execve()  ,read the kernel code,you can find it.